# Changing a certain word's first letter to capital letter

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I want to be able to change a lowercase letter in all mp3 files to uppercase, so for all mp3 files that have the word `featuring` in the file name, changing that to `Featuring`.

Comment: You can use string substitution like `%FileName:featuring=Featuring%`, when variable `%FileName%` contains the file name; the word `featuring` is searched in a case-**in**sensitive manner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service and a questioner should show efforts on having tried to solve the task with code by oneself, here is a small uncommented batch code for this task making the file renames recursively from current directory for all `*.mp3` files containing `featuring` in any case:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /S *featuring*.mp3 2^>nul') do (
    set "FileName=%%~nxF"
    set "NewFileName=!FileName:featuring=Featuring!"
    ren "%%F" "!NewFileName!"
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Hint: There are file managers like *Total Commander* with built-in [multi-rename tool](http://www.ghisler.com/advanced.htm#tutorial_rename) which makes such file renames a trivial tasking without the need of coding skills.